# WKWebview & UIImageView Inside UIScrollView programmatically autolayout Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, wkwebview

I wanted to implement WKWebView and UIImageView Inside a UIScrollView programmatically, but it doesn't fulfill my requirement.I first add UIImageView & WKWebView to scrollView after that I added the scrollView to ViewController subview. I write the Objective-C code for it as below.

```
#import "StoryDetailViewController.h"
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>
@interface StoryDetailViewController ()
//@property(strong,nonatomic) WKWebView *webView;
@end

@implementation StoryDetailViewController{
    UIScrollView* scrollView;
    WKWebView* webView;
    UILabel* title;
    UIImageView* imageView;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self setUpSubview];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

-(void)setUpSubview{

    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]init];
    scrollView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;
    imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
    imageView.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;
    webView = [[WKWebView alloc]init];
    webView.backgroundColor=[UIColor purpleColor];
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;
    [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
    [scrollView addSubview:webView];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    [self addConstraints];
}
-(void)addConstraints{

    [scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:scrollView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0.0]];
    [scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:scrollView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                         multiplier:0.35
                                                           constant:0.0]];
    [scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:scrollView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0.0]];
    [scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:scrollView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0.0]];

    [scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:webView
                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                              toItem:scrollView
                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                          multiplier:1.0
                                                            constant:0.0]];
    [scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:webView
                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                              toItem:scrollView
                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                          multiplier:1.0
                                                            constant:0.0]];
    [scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:webView
                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                              toItem:imageView
                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                          multiplier:1.0
                                                            constant:10.0]];
    [scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:webView
                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                              toItem:scrollView
                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                          multiplier:1.0
                                                            constant:0.0]];
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:scrollView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0.0]];
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:scrollView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0.0]];
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:scrollView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0.0]];
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:scrollView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0.0]];

}
@end
```

**I'm using the WKwebview because the UIWebView is deprecated in Xcode 9 and WKwebview in storyboard supported only from iOS 11 **
So Please help if code is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First you want to put this code in **viewDidLayoutSubviews**

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {

 [self setUpSubview];

}
```

second , you should create a content view inside scrollview and add elements to it but as a work around add these 2 constraints

```
  [scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:scrollView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0.0]];

  [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView
                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                     toItem:self.view
                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                 multiplier:1.0
                                                   constant:0.0]];
```

and remove this as scrollview expects it's size from sub-elements and not vice versa

```
[scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:scrollView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0.0]];
```

third give height for the imageView not that equals to scroll view remove it and give a static height or height proportional to self.view

```
  [imageView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView
                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                     toItem:nil
                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNone
                                                 multiplier:1.0
                                                   constant:200.0]];
```

finally do setp 2,3 with the webview